# Не проходит запись в Базу Данных. Почему?

Tags: php, mysql

Не проходит запись в Базу Данных. Почему? Где ошибка?

pay.php

```
<form id="pay_zpayment" name="pay_zpayment" method="post" action="https://z-payment.com/merchant.php">
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYEE_PURSE" value="<?=$ppu['login_to_robokassa']?>"/>

<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value="<?=$summa_v?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_NO" value="<?=time()?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="FIELD_1" value="<?=$_SESSION['ID_P'][1]?>">

<input type="hidden" name="LMI_PAYMENT_DESC" value="Пополнение кошелька">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="process" value='Пополнить кошелек на сумму <?=$summa_v?>  <?=$rru['cena_valuta']?> через платежный шлюз <?=$kassa?>' >
</form>
```

result_zp.php

```
function ConfirmOrder($IdOrder) {

    require_once('../../../connect/connect.php');

    global $id_user;
    global $summa;

    $id_user=intval($_REQUEST['FIELD_1']);
    $summa=floatval($_REQUEST['LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT']);


    $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM akk WHERE id_akk='".$id_user."'");
    $nr=mysql_num_rows($r);
    if(!$nr) exit();

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO plateg (summa, id_akk, typ, data, opis)  VALUES ('".$summa."', '".$id_user."', 1, NOW(), 'Пополнение кошелька через Z-Payment')");
    include('../../balans.php');

    return true;
}
```

**Обновление**

В службу поддержки я обращался. У них платеж проходит. Мне приходит смс с фактом оплаты в котором указан номер счета, сумма и т.д. Т.е. данные платежная система отправляет, только вот в мою БД не записываются. Непойму почему? Интеркасса же работает.

Функция написанная самой платежной системой:

```
function ConfirmOrder($IdOrder) {
    // Здесь необходимо выполнить все действия по обновлению статуса заказа, 
    // уведомлению клиента, отгрузке товара и пр. действия после получения оплаты заказа
    return true;
}
```

В пустой файл `result_zp.php`

```
echo "<pre>", print_r($_REQUEST, true), "</pre>";  -> Array()
```

Так как вы сказали. Ошибка:

> Номер счета не соответсвует заказу.

Comment: Перед $id_user=intval($_REQUEST['FIELD_1']); сделайте вывод всего массива $_REQUEST вот так: print_r($_REQUEST); и убедитесь, что у вас нет там 'FIELD_1' и 'LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT' P.S. Зачем вы стерли предыдущий вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос был слишком объемный и непонятный. Я его укоротил до функции. Да и на него никто не смог ответить...

Comment: Вам и на этот ни кто не ответит. Обращайтесь в службу поддержки z-payment, чтобы они вам точно сказали как взять нужные данные из транзакции.

Comment: Форма ни коим образом не связана с result_zp.php, поэтому забудьте что на этой форме есть и смотрите что вам приходит в `$_REQUEST`

Comment: И читайте доки, у них даже [пример](https://www.z-payment.com/sample.php) реализации есть

Comment: Про форму я уже в предыдущем вопросе говорил человеку, но он не понимает этого.

Comment: Начните, наконец, отлаживать ваш код. Хотя бы расставьте `error_log()` по скрипту и посмотрите что выполняется, а что - нет и какие параметры на каждой стадии имеются

Comment: Заменяем _исполнение запроса_ к базе на *вывод запроса на консоль* (echo, или как там у вас в php называется). Получаем самый эффективный и народный способ отладки, которым пользовался еще Владимир Ильич Ленин (с айпада). Готов поспорить, что на консоли будет невалидный или некорректный SQL-запрос.

Answer (score 2):

> ...Т.е. данные платежная система отправляет, только вот в **мою БД** не
>   записываются.

Начиная с этого места, все упоминания платежной системы следует забыть и сосредоточиться на работе с твоей БД. Потому что на стороне платёжников все о'кей. У них транзакция подтверждается, её следы сохраняются и все работает. Да и потом, их система для тебя черный ящик, и ты не можешь и не должен знать как оно там работает.

Проблема только в том, что набор данных не попадает **в твою базу**. А проблема эта в 99% случаев - синтаксически неправильный SQL-запрос. Вот его и нужно отлаживать.

Предлагаю для начала вывести динамически создаваемую строку запроса на консоль, скопировать ее в редактор СУБД и попытаться  выполнить. Ошибка сразу себя проявит. А попытки исполнить невалидный запрос к базе (даже разными операторами, средствми и методами) - всё это танцы с бубнами.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Общими усилиями сделал. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае, я бы сменил используемый модуль.
Вместо mysql_*, я бы использовал mysqli_* (для небольшого проекта) или PDO(для проектов побольше).

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM akk WHERE id_akk='{$id_user}'");
```

Когда вставляете запись, должна быть даже временная переменная, которой присваивается данное действие:

```
    $update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO plateg (summa, id_akk, typ, data, opis)
VALUES ('{$summa}', '{$id_user}', 1, NOW(), 'Пополнение кошелька через Z-Payment')");
```

Также, проверьте, существуют ли у Вас данные столбцы, в которые осуществляется `INSERT` запрос.